# Android Proguard change package name manually

Tags: android, proguard

When I was building my application I saw some package name doesn't obfuscate. I think these packages have some `@Keep` annotation classes.

But I want change **package name** manually. For example:

**proguard-rules.txt**

```
-applymapping mapping.txt
```

**mapping.txt**

```
com.data.Net -> com.data.Q
```

I tried this but It doesn't work. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard does not have a standard option to rename packages yet keep their simple class names.

You could create a ProGuard mapping file manually, with lines like:

```
com.example.MyClass -> a.MyClass:
com.example.MyOtherClass -> a.MyOtherClass:
```

You can then use the option **-applymapping mapping.txt**

Comment: Thank you for. (MyClass have @Keep annotation for GSON serialize/deserialize operation) When I do this your opinion I saw again com.example.MyClass not to a.MyClass. Mapping.txt location is same to proguard-rules is it true?

Comment: @kibAr as i understand your comment, mapping location is not same. It should be in **build/outputs/mapping/release** folder inside your app.

Comment: When I was change mapping.txt location I got an exception `Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Proj\qweqwe\mapping.txt (File not found)
Error:Execution failed for task ':qweqwe:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details`